# button onClick="javascript:calleoChat" works well on Html but not in a script

Tags: javascript

in my html, there is a button and it opens chat-bot script.

it perfectly works on html.

but it doesn't work on my script.

```
...
...
<section>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:calleoChat('startChat')">Try it</button>
</section>
```

```
<script>

//button creation
let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "Open Chat-Bot";

//call chat bot script, but it doesn't work
btn.onclick = "javascript:calleoChat('startChat')";
node.appendChild(btn);

//insert button to selected class
document.getElementsByClassName("AddToBagButton__container")[0].appendChild(node);

</script>
```

please refer my sample codes above, and please give me your kind advice to solve this issue.

Comment: is your `<scipt>` tags bottom of the html?

Comment: @callmenikk that is not the issue, the code adds the button. If the script was before the html the button isnt added. Now the functionality of the onclick isnt working

Comment: `node` variable doesn't exist also what is `AddToBagButton__container` we don't know so code is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In an onclick you do not need to add "javscript: ", jou can just put the code;

`onclick="calleoChat('startChat')"`

2. In the script onclick you do not need to put the script in quotes;

`btn.onclick = calleoChat('startChat');`

3. You can also add the event as an eventlistener (this way you can add more):

`btn.addEventListener("click", () => calleoChat("startChat"));`

More info on onclick events:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful feedback. btn.addEventListener("..") works well in my code